# Golang os.FileMode corresponding to drwxrwxr-x?

Tags: go

Which os.FileMode values should I provide to `os.Mkdir` as an argument to have a permission corresponding to drwxrwxr-x?

Answer (score 4):

[Daniel Farrell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69834838/1256452) covers the literal settings for modes, but if you're working on a Unix-like system, there are two other important points:

- For most cases (most files), you should just use `0666`.
- For most of the remaining cases (most directories), you should just use `0777`.

Certain Go code checkers complain about this, but they're just *wrong*.

The reason to use `0666` (`rw-rw-rw-`) and `0777` (`rwxrwxrwx`) every time is that on Unix-like systems, newly created files are created under a *umask* setting.  The protections that the binary program asks for, such as `0777`, are *always reduced*.<sup>1</sup>  The reduction is based on this umask setting.

The most permissive umask setting is `0`.  The least is the rather unusable `0777`.  The *common* settings are `077`, `007`, `022`, and `002`.

Bits that are *set* in the umask get *cleared* in the underlying file permissions.  So a umask setting of `022` means that whatever the *program asks for*, the file winds up being *not writable* by Group or Other.  A program that creates a file using `0666` mode winds up with a file whose actual mode is `0644`, or `rw-r--r--`.

Should the user wish to grant group write permissions, they can run `umask 2`.  Now only the Other `w` bit will be cleared and this file will be mode `rw-rw-r--`.

A umask setting of `077` takes away `---rwxrwx`: that is, my files and directories are now private to me only (and the super-user of course).  One of `027` takes away `----w-rwx`, so that newly created files are now `0640`, and newly created directories (that use `0777`) are now `0750`, or `rwxr-x--`.

One not-entirely-rare exception to the above rules is that *temporary* files created in areas of "unknown security" (os.CreateTemp files for instance), or files that contain any sensitive data, should be created with mode `0600`.  They can then be written out without worrying about the data leaking (except to the super-user as usual), and then if they turn out not to be sensitive after all, the *final* file can be created with the correct permissions.

The really tricky case is when creating a temporary file of unknown security which you are then able to rename (rather than copying) to a file of known-to-be-lower security level, where you'd like to `os.Chmod` the file to the final mode that you'd get by applying the user's umask.  But that's pretty rare.

---

<sup>1</sup>In the special case of umask = 0, no bits are removed.  So the result is the original value.  But that's what the user wanted: to have the reduction be a zero-valued reduction.  We're still reducing the permissions, just with a degenerate case.

Answer (score 3):

`drwxrwxr-x`

each set of `rwx` (`r-x`, etc) is represented by one digit in an octal string where 4 = r, 2 = w, and 1=x.  So Read and write combine to make 6, read and execute (eg executables in `/bin` are `5`, and read-only is `4`.

For files, the most common mode is:

`0644` owner gets read and write, group and other get only read

And for directories, typical is:

`0755` owner gets read, write (create within) and execute (list contents) , group and other get only read.

In your case, you'd need to add 2 to the Group digit to allow any users in the directory's Group to also create files in that directory.